# How to calculate the input impedance and transfer function

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, impedance, transfer-function

I have the following circuit, that is used as a signal conditioning circuit in a audio system project.
I am trying to calculate the transfer function and the Zin(input impedance) and Zout(output impedance)
[image]

in Zin, I know how to calculate the impedance of the rc filter but im getting confused because there are one more resistor of 10M that makes the offset of the voltage.

So, how can i calculate the transfer function,Zin and Zout of this circuit?

Comment: The two 10-Meg resistances are in parallel for the small-signal analysis. This is because you consider the 5-V source at a 0-V ac level (imagine a decoupling cap. on this 5-V line).

Comment: 10M resistor values are too high unless you buy and measure many LM324 ICs to pick ones with very low input bias current. The half the supply voltage divider is wrong because the input bias current pulls the inputs to a high enough voltage where they do not work.

Answer (score 3):

Please label your components in future. It would make answering so much easier. Here's my version of your circuit to simplify things:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbIKTD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are the main points that the rest of the explanation depends on:

1. The op-amp is assumed to have infinite input impedance, and any influence it has on the potential at X, \$v_X\$, is negligible.
2. The op-amp is assumed to have zero output impedance. In fact even a non-ideal op-amp with negative feedback will have an output impedance very close to zero (with some caveats). Therefore its output potential \$v_Y\$ will not be influenced in any way by any load (such as R3, R4, C2 and whatever comes after).
3. The op-amp is configured as a voltage follower, with 100% negative feedback, for a gain of 1. Therefore, \$v_Y = v_X\$
4. The op-amp effectively isolates everything to its left (input side) from everything to its right (output side), due to points 1 and 2 above.

## Thévenin equivalents

Now we can attack the problem. First, make sure you are familiar with [Thévenin's theorem](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/) (here's the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem)).

The input potential divider can be reduced to its Thévenin equivalent, consisting of a single voltage source, and single resistance. The Thévenin voltage source will be half the supply potential:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{TH1} &= 5V \times \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
&= 5V \times \frac{10M\Omega}{10M\Omega+10M\Omega} \\ \\
&= 5V \times \frac{10M\Omega}{20M\Omega} \\ \\
&= 2.5V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The Thévenin resistance \$R_{TH1}\$ will be the combined resistance of R1 and R2 as if they were connected in parallel:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{TH1} &= R_1 \parallel R_2 \\ \\
&= \frac{R_1 \times R_2}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{10M\Omega \times 10M\Omega}{10M\Omega+10M\Omega} \\ \\
&= 5M\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Replace the network consisting of the 5V source supply, and R1 and R2, with their Thévenin equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6RqHl.png)</sup>

We do the same conversion to a Thévenin equivalent for the output potential divider, replacing R3 and R4 with \$R_{TH2}\$, pretending that the voltage source \$v_Y\$ has become a source of one-tenth of \$v_Y\$ (with no internal impedance) like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
v_{TH2} &= v_Y \times \frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_4} \\ \\
&= v_Y \times \frac{1k\Omega}{9k\Omega + 1k\Omega} \\ \\
&= v_Y \times \frac{1k\Omega}{10k\Omega} \\ \\
&= \frac{v_Y}{10} \\ \\ \\
R_{TH2} &= R_3 \parallel R_4 \\ \\
&= 9k\Omega \parallel 1k\Omega \\ \\
&= \frac{9k\Omega \times 1k\Omega}{9k\Omega + 1k\Omega} \\ \\
&= 900\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3mm9m.png)</sup>

Here's the entire circuit with both Thévenin equivalents in place:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6ASYz.png)</sup>

I've added a component with impedance \$Z_L\$, representing some load connected to the output. Without a load, capacitor C2 doesn't pass current, and cannot "AC couple" to anything. It's just there to remind you that in real life there *will* be a load, and you must consider it when calculating transfer functions. If the load is negligible (high impedance), then we can say that there will never be a charge on C2, no voltage across it, and \$V_{OUT} = V_Z\$.

## Input impedance

Due to points 1 and 4 above, anything connected to IN will see, looking into C1, the series connected pair C1 and \$R_{TH1}\$, followed by a zero-impedance voltage source. Therefore:

$$
\begin{aligned}
Z_{IN} &= Z_{C1} + Z_{R_{TH1}} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{sC_1} + R_{TH1} \\ \\
&= \frac{1 + sR_{TH1}C_1}{sC_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{1 + (5\times 10^6)(2\times 10^{-6})s}{(2\times 10^{-6})s} \\ \\
&= \frac{1 + 10s}{(2\times 10^{-6})s} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

## Output impedance

Anything connected to OUT will see, looking back into C2, the series connected pair C2 and \$R_{TH2}\$, followed by a zero-impedance voltage source. Therefore:

$$
\begin{aligned}
Z_{OUT} &= Z_{C2} + Z_{R_{TH2}} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{sC_2} + R_{TH2} \\ \\
&= \frac{1 + sR_{TH2}C_2}{sC_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{1 + (900)(2\times 10^{-6})s}{(2\times 10^{-6})s} \\ \\
&= \frac{1 + (1.8\times 10^{-3})s}{(2\times 10^{-6})s} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

## Transfer function

Divide the circuit into three independent stages (independent due to point 4 above), as I have done above with the red (F), green (G) and blue(H) boxes.

Note that the DC offset of 2.5V introduced by source of \$V_{TH1}\$ can be disregarded when talking of transfer functions in the frequency domain, since small-signal AC analysis treats all nodes of fixed DC potential as if they were ground.

Stage F has output X. It's a potential divider consisting of two elements, C1 and \$R_{TH1}\$. Remembering we are dealing with AC signal amplitudes, as with any potential divider, the signal at X is:

$$ v_X = v_{IN} \times \frac{Z_{R_{TH1}}}{Z_{C1} + Z_{R_{TH1}}} $$

A transfer function is the ratio of output to input:

$$
\begin{aligned}
F(s) &= \frac{v_X}{v_{IN}} \\ \\
&= \frac{Z_{R_{TH1}}}{Z_{C1} + Z_{R_{TH1}}} \\ \\
&= \frac{R_{TH1}}{\frac{1}{sC_1} + R_{TH1}} \\ \\
&= \frac{sR_{TH1}C_1}{1 + sR_{TH1}C_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{(5\times 10^6)(2\times 10^{-6})s}{1 + (5\times 10^6)(2\times 10^{-6})s} \\ \\
&= \frac{10s}{1 + 10s} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Stage G is a unity gain stage:

$$ G(s) = 1 $$

Stage H has input \$v_Y\$. If we ignore the load \$Z_L\$, as I stated before, no current can flow through \$R_{TH2}\$ or \$C_2\$, there can be no voltage across them, and \$V_{OUT} = V_Z = V_{TH2} = \frac{V_Y}{10}\$.

So, in the case where element \$Z_L\$ is missing or has a very very high impedance, the transfer function will simply be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{Z_L\rightarrow \infty}(s) &= \frac{v_{OUT}}{v_Y} \\ \\
&= \frac{\left(\frac{v_Y}{10}\right)}{v_Y} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{10}
\end{aligned}
$$

In the more likely scenario where \$Z_L\$ is appreciable, you must consider the entire network of \$R_{TH2}\$, C2 and \$Z_L\$ as another potential divider, with output \$v_{OUT}\$ taken across \$Z_L\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
v_{OUT} &= v_{TH2} \times \frac{Z_L}{Z_L+Z_{C2}+Z_{R_{TH2}}} \\ \\
&= \frac{v_Y}{10} \times \frac{Z_L}{Z_L+\frac{1}{sC_2}+R_{TH2}} \\ \\
&= \frac{v_Y}{10} \times \frac{sZ_LC_2}{sZ_LC_2+1+sR_{TH2}C_2} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The transfer function \$H\$ will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
H(s) &= \frac{v_{OUT}}{v_Y} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \times \frac{sZ_LC_2}{sZ_LC_2+1+sR_{TH2}C_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \times \frac{sZ_LC_2}{1+C_2(Z_L+R_{TH2})s} \\ \\
&= \frac{Z_L(2\times 10^{-6})(\frac{1}{10})s}{1+(2\times 10^{-6})(Z_L+900)s} \\ \\
&= \frac{Z_L(2\times 10^{-7})s}{1+\left[(2\times 10^{-6})Z_L+(1.8\times 10^{-3})\right]s} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The final step is to find the combined transfer function \$J\$ of all three stages cascaded:

$$
\begin{aligned}
J(s) &= F(s)G(s)H(s) \\ \\
&= \frac{10s}{1 + 10s} \times 1 \times \frac{Z_L(2\times 10^{-7})s}{1+\left[(2\times 10^{-6})Z_L+(1.8\times 10^{-3})\right]s}
\end{aligned}
$$

I will leave that to someone else to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. BUF can be approximated as infinitely high input impedance and zero output impedance, it does isolate left and right circuits. The 5M is the Thevenin/Norton equivalent of two 10M resitors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmpDRh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>